# React hook useEffect() under the hood. Does an effect scheduled with useEffect block the main thread?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In React DOCs, about the `useEffect()` hook, we get that:

***"Effects scheduled with useEffect don’t block the browser from updating the screen."***

> **Tip**
>
> Unlike componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate, effects scheduled with useEffect don’t block the browser from updating the screen.

What does it mean by that exactly?

**Example:** Imagine that I have the following:

- A controlled input
- And a useEffect after 1st render that does some expensive **synchronous** computation.

```
function App() {
  const [inputValue,setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  useEffect(()=>{
    // RUN SOME EXPENSIVE SYNCHRONOUS FUNCTION
  },[]);

  return (
    <input value={inputValue} onChange={()=>setInputValue(event.target.value)}/>
  );

}
```

Does it mean that I would be perfectly able to use my `input` (which is controlled by React using JS, which is single-threaded) even when that heavy synchronous computation is running? If so, how can this be?

Answer (score 7):

#### Class Component

1. Render the virtual dom.
2. `componentDidMount`.
3. Paint to the browser.

#### Functional Component

1. Render the virtual dom.
2. `useLayoutEffect`.
3. Paint to the browser.
4. `useEffect`.

---

If your side effect is asynchronous, there is no difference between `componentDidMount` and `useEffect`. (almost)
But if it is synchronous, `componentDidMount` and `useLayoutEffect` cause a visual lag.